# Compositor and rendered image not the same

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I have set render layers, combined in compositor.
Post processing is checked for compositing.
the rendering rendered all 3 layers but the final outcome is only one fo those layers.
the viewer and the final render is different.

(something that is weird: i tried both cpu and gpu to render, previously does not have this problem but recently when i render after the 1st layer, the img of the first layer is still visible while rendering the second layer, only "overwrite" when the boxes render the portion, i wonder if it is a bug...)

Comment: pls provide us your blendfile (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or upload some screenshots of your compositor. otherwise your question is to vague and can be caused by several reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in your file, the image viewer is set to display the "Bangle" renderlayer:

[image]

Select "Composite" instead to view the output of the compositor.