# GPU render (OpenCL) is not creating an accurate composite- it only renders top "layer"

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am using a Baffin (RX-460 4gb) to render.  I followed the Blender Guru Earth tutorial.  It utilizes cycles.  It basically creates an earth using 3 layers (Earth, Clouds, Atmosphere).

When I CPU render the object, it accurately renders the composite of the three layers.  When I GPU render it only shows the "top" layer- e.g. atmosphere.  A GPU render of each layer is accurate, but it will not produce a composite of all the layers properly.

You can see the correct CPU output versus the [incorrect GPU output](https://www.flickr.com/gp/56904855@N06/4F81f6) .

Comment: GPU vs CPU definitely shouldn't have any effect on the compositing stage of things.. It does look like you may have selected a specific renderlayer in the image viewer (see http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63262/599), but that shouldn't have anything to do with CPU/GPU. If changing that to *composite* that doesn't appear to be the solution, iIs it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: Here is the [Blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_AmtL8_VPkkZ0t3RHgyNFRETHM/view?usp=sharing) with the supporting Nasa images from [Blender Guru's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q8PwcDzb8Y) tutorial that I utilized.  I think you will have to point the image files to the correct location.  I have the output I need from the CPU rendering, but it took 3 hours.  I think if I could get the GPU rendering to work it would substantially reduce this time.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you meant by layers. Even so, your file renders fine on my GPU (GTX 460) after downsampling the textures; otherwise it runs out of memory. I doubt that's the case with yours however, as I find it unlikely that it would successfully render just one of the objects in that manner..

Answer (score 1):

It appears that reducing the size of the textures allows it to render.  However, the output is distorted by noise lines.  No clean image is produced even if I resize the images.  Odd that this would happen with a 4gb card and not a 1gb card.

Perhaps Vulkan will yield better results if it is implemented.  Given the lackluster results with OpenCL, it may make more sense to construct a new method of rendering rather than fixing a broken one.

**Update:  I just tried out RC 2.78 and it works!  It produces an accurate image with a GPU render in half the time!**